# Slack Events Request URL - Unverified Request Error

Tags: javascript, json, http, slack, slack-api

My Slackbot needs to make an HTTP request to Microsoft Azure's Text Analytics API through the Glitch app, but I am receiving the error message below:

`An unverified request was sent to the Slack events Request URL. Request body: undefined`

I suspect the error is probably not related to the Azure API call, but occurs when a request to Glitch is made without the correct verification token, but I've checked my .env file, and the tokens seem to be there.

```
negativity: function(slack, message) {
var obj = { 
  documents: [{
  language: "en",
  id: 1,
  text: "hello it's a great day"
}]};

var JSONString = JSON.stringify(obj);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange= function () {
if (request.readyState==4 && request.status == 200) { 

  var resultText = request.responseText;
     slack.chat.postMessage({
    channel: message.channel,
     text: `inside callback from negativity`
  })

  }
}

request.open("POST", "x");

request.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "x");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
request.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
request.send(JSONString);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help, it looks like `var request = new XMLHttpRequest()` isn’t available on server side JavaScript, and an alternative that worked was https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios.

In addition I installed axios in the console with `npm install --save axios`.

I have attached the improvements to the above code.

```
const axios = require('axios');

// some code

negativity: function(slack, message) {

        axios.post( 'x',
          {
            documents: [{
              language: "en",
              id: 1,
              text: message.text
            }]
          },
          {
            headers: {  
              'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':'x',
              'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
              'Accept' :'application/json'  
            }
          }).then(function (response) {
              var output = response.data;
             });
          }
```